# How do I add sounds to a storyboard in wpf?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, audio

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I use media element seperately for sound.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible...  just drag and drop the sound to your project. It would the appear into your timeline if your using expression blend which makes it easier to manipulate animation in wpf...